# ¿Cómo podría generar un update a 2 tablas con un botón de on y off, en donde on ejecute mis querys y off me lo deje como lo tenía?

Tags: php, mysql

Específicamente deseo que cuando esté prendido en

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejecute mis querys.

Y cuando esté apagado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejecute otro par de querys.

Este es mi código:

```
<body>

  <form method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="ok" id="ok" value="BAJAR SERVICIOS" /> <!-- Un solo boton que envie todos los datos del form -->
  </form>

<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>

</body>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST[ok])) { // Si hay post, ejecuto ambas querys
  mysql_query('Aqui mi query');
  mysql_query('Aqui mi otro query');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<body>

  <form method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="ok" id="ok" value="BAJAR SERVICIOS" /> <!-- Un solo boton que envie todos los datos del form -->


<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" value=true checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
</form>
</body>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST['ok'])) { // Si hay post, ejecuto ambas querys
   if($_POST['onoffswitch'] ){
        mysql_query('Aqui mi query');
   }else{
     mysql_query('Aqui mi otro query');
   }
}
?>
```

Espero haber-te ayudado, te he cambiado un poco el html :)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) [html](/questions/tagged/html)